# Selecting count(*) while checking for a value in the results

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Count, IF(sch.HomeTeamID = 34,true,false) AS Hawaii
FROM schedule sch 
JOIN schools s ON s.ID = 83 
WHERE (sch.HomeTeamID = 83 OR sch.AwayTeamID = 83)
AND sch.SeasonID = 4
```

I'm trying to use count() to simplify my result but also include a field that represents wether any of the results' specific column contained a certain value. Is this possible? I'd basically like a row response with all the info I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to count how many times the home team was 34, do this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as Count, 
    sum(sch.HomeTeamID = 34) AS Hawaii_home_count
...
```

Incidentally, the terse summing of a condition works in mysql only, because in mysql true is 1 and false is 0, so sum(condition) counts how many times it was true (other databases requires the use of a case statement)

Answer (score 0):

What about using a having clause?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Count
FROM schedule sch 
JOIN schools s ON s.ID = 83 
WHERE (sch.HomeTeamID = 83 OR sch.AwayTeamID = 83)
AND sch.SeasonID = 4
Having sch.HomeTeamID = 34
```